# Is there anyway to get notified when a ref gets updated in JGit?

Tags: jgit

Is there any way to get notified, when I add/update/delete a ref in the bare git repository? Maybe through listener or any other way in JGit. I see `org.eclipse.jgit.events.RefsChangedListener` and `org.eclipse.jgit.events.RefsChangedEvent`. However, `RefsChangedEvent` doesn't seem to give useful information like which ref got affected and what was the type of change to ref.

Basically, I need to perform some operation after a particular ref gets updated.

Any hints will be useful.

Comment: AFAIK, `RefsChangedEvent` is the correct event to listen to. You can use  `repository.getRefDatabase().getRefs()` to get a snapshot of all refs and then compare the result with a current snapshot when this event occurs.

Comment: I see a weird behavior with `org.eclipse.jgit.events.RefsChangedListener#onRefsChanged`. It is not invoked immediately when a ref is changed. Rather it gets invoked when next time when I try to access the changed ref by `org.eclipse.jgit.lib.RefDatabase#exactRef(java.lang.String)`.